# create csv file using Spring MVC

Tags: java, csv, spring-mvc, apache-poi

I Need to create a CSV file using JAVA.

Earlier I created excel file using `HSSFBook` from Apache POI, and from SPRING support I used `AbstarctExcelView.buildExcelDocument()`.

Similarly, want to ask is there any predefined class like `HSSFBook` from Apache POI (or from any vendor) **to create a csv file**. And their spring supports like  `AbstarctExcelView class`.

Comment: There's no spring support view for CSV, see children of AbstractView.

Answer (score 0):

Try Super CSV ,this has POJO support. You can easily create the csv using your pojos. I prefer this than Apache POI. https://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/examples_writing.html

Comment: Thank you, This makes easy to my program